Force AVCaptureDevice to main (wide-angle) instead of ultra-wide camera
I am playing around with this tutorial project:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/capturingphotos-captureandsave
This app uses ultra-wide camera (0.5x) by default but I want to switch to main camera (1x) because quality of uw photos are worse. But I can't see any options, only to switch between front/back:
class Camera: NSObject {
    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var isCaptureSessionConfigured = false
    private var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    private var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    private var videoOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    private var sessionQueue: DispatchQueue!
    
    private var allCaptureDevices: [AVCaptureDevice] {
        AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInTrueDepthCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInDualWideCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInDualWideCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified).devices
    }
    
    private var frontCaptureDevices: [AVCaptureDevice] {
        allCaptureDevices
            .filter { $0.position == .front }
    }
    
    private var backCaptureDevices: [AVCaptureDevice] {
        allCaptureDevices
            .filter { $0.position == .back }
    }
    
    private var captureDevices: [AVCaptureDevice] {
        var devices = [AVCaptureDevice]()
        #if os(macOS) || (os(iOS) && targetEnvironment(macCatalyst))
        devices += allCaptureDevices
        #else
        if let backDevice = backCaptureDevices.first {
            devices += [backDevice]
        }
        if let frontDevice = frontCaptureDevices.first {
            devices += [frontDevice]
        }
        #endif
        return devices
    }
    
    private var availableCaptureDevices: [AVCaptureDevice] {
        captureDevices
            .filter( { $0.isConnected } )
            .filter( { !$0.isSuspended } )
    }
    
    private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice? {
        didSet {
            guard let captureDevice = captureDevice else { return }
            logger.debug("Using capture device: \(captureDevice.localizedName)")
            sessionQueue.async {
                self.updateSessionForCaptureDevice(captureDevice)
            }
        }
    }

...
 private func initialize() {
        sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
        
        captureDevice = availableCaptureDevices.first ?? AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateForDeviceOrientation), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }


You don't need all these "discovery" procedures, just use AVCaptureDevice.default instead of availableCaptureDevices. The AVCaptureDevice.default will choose the best camera for a device. But if you need a specific device, you can provide it as well, for example AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
